# Is online roleplay haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Is it haram? can I set my username to "Joseph Stalin" or "Adolf Hitler" and have a picture of either of them on my profile in a website, for example YouTube? it's a username, so I'm not saying I'm Hitler or Stalin, I don't think if that counts as a lie, and I'm not being racist or saying anything bad those two did.

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61558/is-using-fake-names-another-persons-name-haram

Answer (score -1):

If this isn’t a username IMO this is a no go because this is not nice to do and because these people are dead I’m not sure if that’s haram but I wouldn’t risk it my friend stay on the safe side I’m leaning towards haram or makruh be on the safe side brother and Allah knows best